# I can set a .doc file with permission to view only(no copy content, not editable). Can I do the same thing in a .java file?

Tags: java, file-permissions

Basically I want to deliver a java code which can only be viewed, neither edited or used any other way. Is it possible.

Note: This is not about delivering the .class file. The client wanna see the code in .java file.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

You can set file as read only. But the viewer can also change permission!.

Answer (score 1):

If they can read it they can copy it.  You could make it harder by sending the file as a set of PNG or JPEG screenshots, forcing them to retype (or use a good OCR program).  If you are required to let them read the Java code, then they can make a copy.

There's nothing you can do about it.